# n-by-n matrix homework assignment

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment where I am asked to produce an n-by-n matrix with user input.
I have tried several solutions but nothing seems to work. I guess it's a relatively simple assignment for many of you.

This is the assignment text:
Write a method that displays an n-by-n matrix using the following signature: public static void printMatrix(int n)
Each element is 0 or 1, which is generated randomly. Write a test program that prompts the user to enter n and displays an n-by-n matrix.

My latest attempt is the following (Obviously I am not invoking the method yet):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        //Variable Declarations
        int n;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Ask User for the Value of n
        System.out.print("Enter n: "); 
        n = input.nextInt();    

    } 

    public static String printMatrix(int n){ 
        String result = " "; 
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){ 
            result += "\n"; 
            for (int y = 0; y < n; y++){ 
                result += (int)(Math.random() * 2); 
            } 
        } 
        return result.substring(1); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Let us know what you tried. we are not here for homework ..:)

Comment: *I have tried several solutions...* Please show us your best attempt...

Comment: I have updated my post:) not at all working though

Comment: Output of `Math.random()` needs to be rounded and the numbers on rows need some spaces or tabs to separate them, but otherwise, it's not that bad :) . Update: ok, multiplying by 2 and casting does the "rouding" job as well.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment David? What do you mean by "multiplying by 2 and casting does the "rouding" job as well"?

Comment: Oh...sorry. I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call `printMatrix`. Call `printMatrix(n)` after `n = input.nextInt();`. You may want to print the result in the method itself (Because that's what it's name implies), and change it's type to void, or print the returned String in main.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is completed your answer

```
public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter n: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        new TestProgram().printMatrix(n);
    }

    public void printMatrix(int n){
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < n; y++){
                System.out.print((int)(Math.random() * 2)+ "");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package matrix;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter n: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();

          for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < n; y++){
                System.out.print((int)(Math.random() * 2)+ "");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```